Problem with a component no re-rendering in a React app
I am learning React and I am currently working on a simple weather app as a way to practice. It works fine but I have been stuck on a problem for quite a while now.
The app has 2 pages (using react-router-dom), a home page with an input form to look for a city (using api.mapbox.com). When a city is clicked from the results list, there is a preview of the city weather (api.openweathermap.org), then the user can click on a + button to save this city (using local storage). The saved cities are showing as cards on the home page. It is possible to remove a city from the saved cities using a button at the bottom of the weather page. It simply removes the city from the array stored in the local storage, then it redirects to the home page.
The problem is that I still see the "removed" city card after the redirection, I have to refresh the page to see it removed. I think I need to use the useEffect hook to re-render the city list after having the city removed, but I can't get it to work. I am missing something, but can't figure out what.
Below is my CityList.jsx component, the one that renders the saved cities of the home page :
import { CityListCard } from "./CityListCard";

let savedCities

const getCities = async () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('savedCities')) {
        savedCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedCities'))
        const OWMAppId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        const units = 'metric'
        const langapi = 'en'

        savedCities.map(async (city, index) => {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=${city.coords.lat}&lon=${city.coords.lng}&exclude={part}&appid=${OWMAppId}&units=${units}&lang=${langapi}`, {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            const data = await response.json()
            savedCities[index].weather = data
        })
    }
}

await getCities()

export function CityList() {
    return <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        {savedCities &&
            savedCities.map(city => (
                <CityListCard key={city.id} city={city} />
            ))
        }
    </div>
}

I think I have to add a useEffect with a dependency on savedCities, but as a hook cannot be inside a function, I don't know how to make it work.
Any help appreciated

There's multiple things wrong (well not exactly wrong, but its not the "reactive" way to do it) with your code.

You are declaring variables outside of your React component. This makes it non-reactive, which means React won't know when its updated so it won't re-render the component.
You are making an API call outside the component as well, again, the React component has no idea about this call being made, what if you wanted to show a loader while this call is being made? How would the component know about its status?
Also, you are updating a locally made variable outside the function
scope inside the async function call, ideally functions shouldn't update a variable outside its scope, it should return some form of data, which in turns updates variable.

In order to fix your component, you need to learn how React expects your components to be written, mainly understand the use of hooks, the 2 major ones being useState and useEffect.
Update variables which have been declared using useState will tell react to re-render it any time it detects a change in that variable.
useEffect is mainly used for side-effects, which means any operations or behaviors that occur in a component after rendering, and that don't directly impact the current component render cycle. These side effects can include tasks such as data fetching, subscriptions, manually changing the DOM, or other interactions with the outside world.
You can read more about those on the React website - https://react.dev/reference/react/hooks
Now fixing up your component, it should look somewhat like this, might not exactly work but you will get a fair idea
import { CityListCard } from "./CityListCard";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";



const getCities = async () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('savedCities')) {
        const savedCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedCities')  || '[]')
        const OWMAppId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        const units = 'metric'
        const langapi = 'en'

        savedCities.map(async (city, index) => {
            const response = await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=${city.coords.lat}&lon=${city.coords.lng}&exclude={part}&appid=${OWMAppId}&units=${units}&lang=${langapi}`, {
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
                }
            })
            const data = await response.json()
            savedCities[index].weather = data
        })
    }
}



export function CityList() {
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // make the API call here and set the state
    getCities().then((data) => {
      setCities(data);
    });
  }, []); // dependencies variables are added here to re-run the effect when they change, if 

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      {cities &&
        cities.map((city) => <CityListCard key={city.id} city={city} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

